# <Unity2d> Distance Joint 2d rotating platform doesn't work perfectly

Tags: unity-game-engine

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/15ubsuo/distance_joint_2d_rotating_platform_doesnt_work/

When the platform descends, it floats between the player and the platform, causing the player to move strangely.
The platform contains code that sets the player from collisionStay and collisionExit to the platform's child.
The platform contains a distance point 2d component and uses transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity; to stop the rotation.
The platform has parent platform, and the parent platform has a rotating code as a rotate function.

```
void Update()
{
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * degreePerSecond);
}
```

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
if(collision.transform.position.y > transform.position.y)
{
collision.transform.SetParent(transform);
}
}
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
collision.transform.SetParent(null);
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of your post. You decided to turn it into a question on StackOverflow. But I do not see a question according to [ask]. Instead I get the impression that you are trying to provide a solution to a question on a different platform. Apart from that, you might find that StackOverflow users tend to get a little trigger-happy when a post gives the impression of mostly consisting of a link to a different community and little helpful info otherwise.

Comment: In general if physics are involved you will probably rather move your stuff in `FixedUpdate` .. also if this has a Rigidbody you shouldn't be moving it via Transform then.